# How to change a whole element with an already existing value with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have some original file with a header I want to change for another one (stored i other file):

original file:

```
<doc1>
    <header>
        <a>aaaa</a>
        <b>bbbb</b>
    </header>
    <content>
      <z>zzzzzzzzzzzzz</z>
    </content>
</doc1>
```

new header (in a file):

```
<header>
    <c>cccc</c>
</header>
```

expected result:

```
    <doc1>
    <header>
        <c>cccc</c>
    </header>
    <content>
      <z>zzzzzzzzzzzzz</z>
    </content>
</doc1>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mhm.. this doesn't seem a problem.. Have you tried simply learning XSLT? we can't write your code for you ;)

Comment: There is a tag for this: `homework`

Comment: Are you asking for how to deal with multiple input source?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution. :)

Comment: thank you all for your help and comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation** (for demo-only purposes the new header is imbedded in the XSLT stylesheet):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <my:header>
   <header>
    <c>cccc</c>
   </header>
 </my:header>

 <xsl:variable name="vHeaderDoc" select="document('')/*/my:header"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="header">
     <xsl:copy-of select="$vHeaderDoc/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<doc1>
    <header>
        <a>aaaa</a>
        <b>bbbb</b>
    </header>
    <content>
        <z>zzzzzzzzzzzzz</z>
    </content>
</doc1>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<doc1>
    <header xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my">
    <c>cccc</c>
   </header>
    <content>
        <z>zzzzzzzzzzzzz</z>
    </content>
</doc1>
```

**In the *real* case you will have**:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vHeaderDoc" select="document('Header.xml')"/>
```

and the `header` document will be in the file named `'Header.xml'` that resides in the same directory as the XSLT stylesheet (if in another directory, then change the document URL accordingly).

In the real case, no `xsl:` namespace node will be copied on the `header` element.

**Do note**: The use of the standard XSLT function **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document)**.

Comment: +1 for having a better answer than mine :) - although you've left Marc with having to do no work & obviously it's then no fun ;)

Comment: Thank you Dimitre! In my research I found document() function but I wasn't sure it was the optimum way. I trid to +1 your answer but I'm new and I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Thank you gef for your help... don't worry about the fun... I have plenty of work to do in my project. :-)

Comment: @Marc: you are welcome. :) Don't worry about not having yet the right to upvote -- you'll accumulate the necessary points very soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an external document then you need to use the xslt document function.

e.g./

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcombxslt/
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/03/06/xslt.html

Comment: +1 from me. I personally believe that a good code example and explanation count much more than just providing a link -- at least the dialog with the OP can continue smoothly and they can ask any questions they have on the provided solution.